# Is there something specific you need to do to finish the endless paths sword quest?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

Im on level 13 of Od Nua in the pillars of eternity. im in the room with the secret door and a table. Everybody JUST keeps saying kill the enemies in the room and then click the table to open the door.
The table is NOT click-able. is there something else i have to do first??

I have the 3 other pieces of the sword and only need the pommel from the room i cant get into. HELP!
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid you have been mislead. I can assure you that this door has nothing to do with the "sword quest" (`The Blade of the Endless Paths` task I assume).

Pieces of that sword are located on levels **2** (Xaurip hut), **5** (hidden treasury), **9** (hidden room) and **12** (with mad Vithrack). The door you put a picture of, is located on level **13**.

As an additional info - I've been there, opened that door. It's just another treasure room, two containers with some magical quipment, nothing truly memorable. I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: Hmm... I have since learned that the only way to open this door is to absorb the knowladge of the other Watcher that was in the path. ( M something ). When speaing to him you can at the end choose to set him free, absorb his wisdom or kill. If you dont chose to absorb you cant interact with the table and CANT open the door. So it isnt a bug but a broken quest for me coz i choose WRONG! WAY TO GO DEVELOPERS!!

Comment: @Cherubel Some decisions have consequences. This is a good thing IMO.

Comment: @MichaelCampbell Consequenses are great in RPG games! have played RPG games since 1996 and never wanted to play anything else. Problem in this case is that it leaves you with a broken quest chain and if you want to redo it you have to reload and redo 10+ hours of gameplay. Atrocious & appaling.

Comment: @Cherubel What quest chain? If you mean The Blade of the Endless Paths like you said in the question, you were just told that this has nothing to do with that. You do not need to enter that room to complete it. See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eK7mjRCPDKg

Comment: @Cherubel Finished Endless Paths yesterday, added some info about it to the answer.

Comment: @Deltharis ty man! i really taught that the last piece of the sword was in that room. Havent played since coz i felt cheated. :( Guess i can jump back in and finish the game while i dry my eyes off ;-)